# Thrust equivalent of Open MP code

Tags: multithreading, random, thrust, montecarlo, openmp

The code i'm trying to parallelize in open mp is a Monte Carlo that boils down to something like this:

```
int seed = 0;
std::mt19937 rng(seed); 
double result = 0.0;
int N = 1000;

#pragma omp parallel for
for(i=0; x < N; i++)
{
    result += rng()
}
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

I want to make sure that the state of the random number generator is shared across threads, and the addition to the result is atomic.

Is there a way of replacing this code with something from thrust::omp.  From the research that I did so far it looks like thrust::omp is more of a directive to use multiple CPU threads rather than GPU for some standard thrust operations.

Comment: Do you want to run the code on the GPU?  Or just on the CPU?  The thrust OMP [device backend](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Device-Backends) does not use the GPU.  Instead of "multiple CPU threads rather than **CPU**" did you intend to say "multiple CPU threads rather than **GPU**" ?

Comment: I edited the question.  Your observation is correct, my calculations are too complicated to run on GPU, instead I want to run on multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use thrust to do something similar, with (parallel) execution on the host CPU using OMP threads underneath the thrust OMP [backend](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Device-Backends).  Here's one example:

```
$ cat t535.cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/system/omp/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/system/omp/vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  unsigned N = 1;
  int seed = 0;
  if (argc > 1)  N = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2)  seed = atoi(argv[2]);
  std::mt19937 rng(seed);
  unsigned long result = 0;

  thrust::omp::vector<unsigned long> vec(N);
  thrust::generate(thrust::omp::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), rng);
  result = thrust::reduce(thrust::omp::par, vec.begin(), vec.end());
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -o t535 t535.cpp -fopenmp -lgomp
$ time ./t535 100000000
214746750809749347

real    0m0.700s
user    0m2.108s
sys     0m0.600s
$
```

For this test I used Fedora 20, with CUDA 6.5RC, running on a 4-core Xeon CPU (netting about a 3x speedup based on `time` results).  There are probably some further "optimizations" that could be made for this particular code, but I think they will unnecessarily clutter the idea, and I assume that your actual application is more complicated than just summing random numbers.

Much of what I show here was lifted from the thrust direct system access page but there are several comparable methods to access the OMP backend, depending on whether you want to have a flexible, retargettable code, or you want one that specifically uses the OMP backend (this one specifically targets OMP backend).

The thrust::reduction operation guarantees the "atomicity" you are looking for.  Specifically, it guarantees that two threads are not trying to update a single location at the same time.  However the use of `std::mt19937` in a multithreaded OMP app is outside the scope of my answer, I think.  If I create an ordinary OMP app using the code you provided, I observe variability in the results due (I think) to some interaction between the use of the `std::mt19937` rng in multiple OMP threads.  This is not something thrust can sort out for you.

Thrust also has [random number generators](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__random.html), which are designed to work with it.

Comment: That looks like a very neat solution; I'll have to adapt my code as the random component is more complicated that just rand(), the result is a matrix (I'd have to write my own reduction).

I also need access to some global variables (declared outside the threads).  For the sake of the example I would have to add to each random number a value indexed in an array of length N declared in main().  How would that work?

Also, is there a way of controlling the number of threads?

Comment: You can control the number of threads used by any OMP program using the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable, and probably there are other methods, although I don't know of a thrust way to do it.  It's not going to be possible to answer your other question in the space of comments.  Thrust can add one vector to another in a variety of ways, one being `thrust::transform`. If you want to make use of thrust, you're going to have to learn the basics of the algorithms and datatypes it uses.  I'd suggest starting with the [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

Comment: Also have a look at Thrust's [monte carlo example program](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/monte_carlo.cu).