# Calling a thrust functor on the host to execute multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, thrust

I know that calls to a functor using `thrust::for_each` with data in `thrust::host_vector`'s have a parallel execution policy, but do they actually execute in parallel?

If not, what would be the correct way to invoke these knowing that the system I'm running this on is virtualized so that all cores appear to be on the same machine?

[EDIT]

I realize that there is such a thing as `thrust::omp::par`, however, I can't seem to be able to to find a full Thrust example using OpenMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, thrust operations dispatched on the "host" are not run in parallel.  They use a single host thread.

If you want to run thrust operations in parallel on the CPU (using multiple CPU threads) then the recommended practice would be to use the thrust OpenMP backend.

A fully worked example is [here](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Direct-System-Access).

Another worked example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311538/thrust-equivalent-of-open-mp-code).

Comment: I have a follow up question: So if I were to use a (custom) functor, would define it as `__device__` or `__host__`?

Comment: It seems that it should be `__host__`, even though either should work

Comment: `__device__` and `__host__` are not the same as the thrust backend.  For thrust "host" operations, the functor must include `__host__` decoration.  For thrust "device" backend operations which use the GPU as the backend, the functor must include the `__device__` decoration.  For all CPU-based backends (including OMP), the functor must include the `__host__` decoration.  The reason for this is that `__host__` and `__device__` don't mean exactly the same thing as thrust "host" and thrust "device" backend.